# Contextual filter only working on one URL

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks, views

I've been going through posts such as [View block not accepting contextual filter argument](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87099/view-block-not-accepting-contextual-filter-argument), [Contextual filter on Views Block file not found](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41310/contextual-filter-on-views-block-file-not-found?rq=1), [How do I get a block to use a URL to configure a contextual filter?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/how-do-i-get-a-block-to-use-a-url-to-configure-a-contextual-filter), [Contextual filters help](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12981/contextual-filters-help), [Contextual filter with a block view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27818/contextual-filter-with-a-block-view) and more to find the solution or my issue with no luck.

In short my contextual filter only works on 1 of 5 pages I want it to work on (they other 4 pages doesn't return any results). The working page is `label/artists`

I've got a taxonomy vocabulary called `site_sections` and an `artist` content-type. I've got a View Block of `artist` teasers, that I want to filter contextually by a part of the url alias.

I've got a term reference on each artist node to the `site_section` terms which are

- `label`
- `publicity`
- `shop`
- `management`
- `wholesale`

My view is a block showing artist teasers. The block is displayed on these URL aliases:

- `label/artists`
- `publicity/artists`
- `shop/artists`
- `management/artists`
- `wholesale/artists`

My contextual filter:

1. Content: Site section (field_site_section)

**WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE**

2. Provide default value: Raw value from URL
3. Path component: 1
4. Use path alias: Y

**WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS AVAILABLE OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED**

5. Specify validation criteria: Taxonomy term (site section)
6. Filter value type: Term name converted to term ID
7. Transform dashes in URL to spaces in term name filter values: Y

Comment: Have you considered making 5 clones of the block and manually filtering them for the taxonomy for each site section?  Or did you use taxonomy because you expect the site owner to add more sections?

Comment: Yes and yes:). But I'm the site owner so it might not be a disaster. I'm also about to get into the same challenge with a commerce product display. My main focus was to keep the site as clean as possible. You don't think it's possible to achieve via contextual filters?

Comment: And it might sound like a silly question, but I assume the spelling of your taxonomy and your paths are exactly the same including case (as shown in your question)?

Comment: It wasn't actually, the terms were written with 1st letter capitalized. It's changed now, ran `drush cc all` - still not working

Comment: ...and you definitely have published artists that contain the other taxonomies?

Comment: yes sir, doublechecked 'n all:)

Comment: Can you confirm that you have not set the taxonomy aliases to conflict with the paths you are trying to use. Disable the view and try to navigate to those paths. It it brings up the taxonomy display re-adjust your path aliases for taxonomy.

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment as I did not take into account that it was a block view. I have duplicated your setup and I am getting the correct result, so your method is correct. There must be something small you are overlooking.

Comment: Thanks @J.Reynolds. That's really good to know. I really appreciate you took the time to do this. I'll update the thread when I hopefully find whatever is causing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found my error.

On the artist block configuration I'd copy pasted urls except for the label, it said:

```
`label/artists shop/artists/ management/artists/ wholesale/artists/ publicity/artists/`
```

Removing the trailing slashes did the trick.